# Python C interoperability

Tags: python, c, interop

I wish to wrap an existing C (pure C that is. No C++) library into Python so that I can call it from Python scripts. Which approach among the various available (C Api, SWIG etc.) would be the most suitable?

Comment: 3 answers, 3 different suggestions. not exactly what you were hoping for I'd guess ;)

Comment: Suggest to close as subjective and argumentative. All what is the best questions are like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

go with Ctypes, it is part of standard distribution and works very well.
basically you can wrap C structures and types in python classes, as well as functions. Some types and functionality is already provided by library.

[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)

couple caveats though: passing triple pointers to C routines is not obvious (if you have to), and I could not get it to work with static libraries on Linux, DLL and shared objects are fine.

Comment: Thanks unknown. I didn't even know ctypes existed. It looks simpler to use and yet just as effective as others.

Answer (score 4):

SWIG is great for doing this. Here is a sample tutorial: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is "pure" C you might consider using [Pyrex](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Pyrex)/Cython. This is not a voting issue and Cython has already been mentioned. I am just clarifying why it is a better choice for pure C.