# How to call C functions from python?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a scenario where GUI (Developed in VB) is sending commands to the target system application developed in C language (Xilinx).

User on a PC sends the commands to target using GUI.

But now I need to remove the GUI and want to send commands (call C functions in target system application) using Python.

I found some useful info from ctypes but don't know the exact procedure so getting budded up frequently.

Question :

Can anyone tell me the exact procedure to develop a python script for this. I know fair amount of python scripting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python C interoperability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144542/python-c-interoperability)

Answer (score 1):

Invoke a SWIG wrapper to make C functions look like Python functions.  Take a look at this [example](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example).

Comment: Thanks for replying Sanjay,

Well using SWIG I may need to edit the C source files which is not favourable in my case, I need some way in python to just access the C source code, some way of interfacing with C Source code